# Calculate days before next third Friday in a month for a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series in pandas Dataframe which looks like following:

```
time                          A           B
2012-06-11 09:25:00.005001    2572.4      2.589
2012-06-11 09:30:00.005004    2573.2      2.592
2012-06-11 09:31:00.005000    2572.6      2.592
2012-06-11 09:32:00.004996    2572.2      2.591
2012-06-11 09:33:00.005003    2570.0      2.589
2012-06-18 09:34:00.004999    2571.2      2.590
2012-06-18 09:35:00.004996    2572.0      2.591
2012-06-18 09:36:00.005002    2572.2      2.590
```

Is there a way that I can quickly calculate the days before next third Friday in a month? In this case it would look like:

```
[4,4,4,4,4,32,32,32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function together with the [`WeekOfMonth` offset class](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) and its rollforward method for moving a date forward or backward to the next or previous “offset date”.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import WeekOfMonth

wom = WeekOfMonth(week=2, weekday=4)
df['days'] = df['d'].apply(lambda x: (wom.rollforward(x) - x).days)
```

Answer (score 0):

3rd Friday? [you mean when options expire?](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/expirationdate.asp)  :)

Not sure if there already is a built-in [anchored offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets), but a work-around can be:

```
>>> offset = dt.timedelta(days=60)
>>> first = df['time'].min().date() - offset
>>> last  = df['time'].max().date() + offset
>>> ts = pd.date_range(first, last, freq='W-Fri').to_series()
>>> a = ts.groupby(ts.dt.month).nth(2).values
>>> i = np.searchsorted(a, df['time'], side='right')
>>> a[i] - df['time']
0    3 days 14:34:59.994999
1    3 days 14:29:59.994996
2    3 days 14:28:59.995000
3    3 days 14:27:59.995004
4    3 days 14:26:59.994997
5   31 days 14:25:59.995001
6   31 days 14:24:59.995004
7   31 days 14:23:59.994998
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

modifying the last 3 lines you may get number of days:

```
>>> a = ts.groupby(ts.dt.month).nth(2).dt.date.values
>>> i = np.searchsorted(a, df['time'].dt.date, side='right')
>>> a[i] - df['time'].dt.date
0    4 days
1    4 days
2    4 days
3    4 days
4    4 days
5   32 days
6   32 days
7   32 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rollforward` method of the `WeekofMonth` offset class:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

df['days'] = [(WeekOfMonth(week=2, weekday=4).rollforward(d)-d).days 
    for d in df['time']]
```

Comment: Would it not be better to initiate the WeekOfMonth object only once? In this solution you will initiate it once per iteration